# Double for loop in haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to make a new list with the 2nd number of a tuple of if the first number is in the first list, here a example `helplist [0,2] [(0,"a"),(3,"x"),(5,"y"),(1,"b"),(2,"c")] = ["a","c"]`

I've tryed so many combinations but without success, here my code:

```
helplist :: [Int] -> [(Int,Char)] -> [Char]
helplist (x:xs) ((i,g):gs) | (x == i) = g : helplist xs gs
helplist _ _ = []
```

In java I'd done a 2x for loop but in haskell I just know recursion.

Comment: You here iterate over both lists "concurrently". But in a declarative language you should not think in terms of "loops".

Comment: what should `helplist [0,2] [(0,"a"),(0,"b")]` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension* here:

```
helplist :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
helplist xs gs = [ g | x <- xs, (i, g) <- gs, x == i ]
```

Or you can try to filter the list based on the value of another list, like:

```
helplist :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
helplist xs gs = concatMap (\x -> map snd (filter (\(i, _) -> x == i) gs)) xs
```

Comment: What does the Eq a => do here? wouldnt it work without it?

Comment: @Kevin: it is a type constraint that says that `a` should be an instance of the `Eq` typeclass. It is necessary to perform an `x == i`. An `Int` for example is an instance of the `Eq` typeclass, hence for `[Int] -> [(Int, Char)] -> [Char]`, this will work. But it will thus work for more types than just `Int`s (`String`s, `Char`s, `Integer`s, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Haskell already has a function for looking up a *single* value in an association list:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

All you need to do is map that (appropriately applied to your list) over your keys.

```
> helpList keys table = map (\x -> lookup x table) keys
> helpList [0,2] [(0,"a"),(3,"x"),(5,"y"),(1,"b"),(2,"c")]
[Just "a",Just "c"]
```

Well, almost. This gives you back a list of `Maybe String` values. If you are sure each lookup will succeed (or simply don't care about lookups that fail), you can use the `catMaybes` function from `Data.Maybe` to drop the `Nothing` responses and extract the actual values from their `Just` wrappers.

```
> import Data.Maybe
> helpList keys table = catMaybes $ map (\x -> lookup x table) keys
> helpList [0,2] [(0,"a"),(3,"x"),(5,"y"),(1,"b"),(2,"c")]
["a","c"]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Just ["a", "c"]` be a very resonable result in this particular case? So `sequence` could be a handy function here.

Comment: In this case, there wouldn't be a clear difference in meaning between `Just []` and `Nothing`, so there seems little reason to have a return type of `Maybe [a]` instead of `[a]`.

Comment: Vote for this answer, love answer that not try to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to write Java in Haskell, but you don't get any benefits from Haskell or functional programming that way. For comparison with the other answer, here's Haskell with a strong Java accent, the way you initially imagined:

```
helplist :: [Int] -> [(Int,Char)] -> [Char]
-- For each thing to find
helplist (x:xs) gs = findOne x gs ++ helplist xs gs
  where
    findOne :: Int -> [(Int,Char)] -> [Char]
    -- For each element in the list
    findOne x ((i,g):gs) | (x == i) = g : findOne x gs
    findOne x (_:gs) = findOne x gs
    findOne _ _ = []
helplist _ _ = []
```

It does the job:

```
*Main> helplist [0,2] [(0,'a'),(3,'x'),(5,'y'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
"ac"
```

But since this approach is a bad fit for Haskell, it ends up being both longer, more awkward to write, and harder to follow than the equivalent Java code.

My suggestion for the most straight forward Haskell implementation is instead to say "I want to find (`filter`) all tuples where the first element is in a list (`elem`), and for each of them (`map`) pick the second element (`snd`):

```
helplist targets tuples = map snd $ filter (\(x, _) -> x `elem` targets) tuples
```